# Trying to count values with multiple criteria

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have a file that contains a planner with dates in the lines and the roles of my team members in the columns.

I need to be able to count how many people are working per day and per role.

[image]
I need to get the sum per Role and for a specific date, with the date being a variable so I just create a cell with the date and change it there to easily filter for the different days.
Basically, for the 13th, I would get "2" for Role 1 and 0 for Role 2.

Then, if I want to get the results for the 14th, I go and change it in the cell that I am using to store the date (remember it is a variable in my formulas) and I get 5 for Role 1 and 3 for Role 2.

Is it possible?

Thank you all for sharing your knowledge!

Comment: There are too many unknowns still. What is the sheet name of the raw data? What range is it in? Where should the results/report go? Which cell will hold the date? In the original data, are the dates real numerical dates or strings? The best way to receive helps is to share a link to a sample sheet that is set up as realistically as possible and where you have manually entered the results you want to see for the sample data set.

Answer (score 0):

The answer comprises three parts:
1 - a Data validation (dropdown) cell where the date can be chosen
2 - a range that can be used for the Data validation cell
2 - an output range containing a query that references the dropdown cell.

**Data validation cell (dropdown)**

- In the example below, this is cell F3. And the data Validation range = $I$4:$I$33
- The green background is just to highlight the cell. It is NOT conditional formatting.

**Range for the Data Validation**

- In the example below, this is cell I3. It contains this formula:
- `={"Date List";query(transpose(B1:W1),"select Col1 where Col1 is not null")}`

**An output range**

- Enter this formula in cell F4.

  - `=query({A2:C4},"select Col1, sum(Col"&(MATCH(F3,B1:W1,0)+1)&") group by Col1 label Col1 'Category', sum(Col"&(MATCH(F3,B1:W1,0)+1)&") 'Number of staff'")`

**Logic**

- Cell F3 contains a dropdown selection of the dates in Row#1 of the source data.
- The data is created by transposing the date cells
- The output cells are generated by the query.

  - the key is `(MATCH(F3,B1:W1,0)+1)`
  - this looks for a match of the date in Cell F3 (the dropdown) among the date values in Row#1
  - it returns an index number; add "+1" to the index to allow for Column A in the query range.
  - result is something like "Col2" or "Col3", etc so that the query will sum the appropriate column that matches the date selected in cell F3

---

**SAMPLE**

[image: snapshot]